# How do I call a declared array variable in a where clause in postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to build a declared array from all the dogs that share the same family_id and query the dog_characteristics table using the array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_dog_characteristics_guarantor_id()
  RETURNS trigger AS $$
  DECLARE dog_ids INT[];

  BEGIN
    SELECT id into dog_ids FROM dogs WHERE dogs.family_id = OLD.id;
    IF ((OLD.family_id IS NOT NULL) && ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dog_ids) > 0)) THEN
      UPDATE
        dog_characteristics
      SET
        guarantor_id = NEW.guarantor_id
      WHERE
        dog_characteristics.account_id = OLD.account_id
        AND dog_characteristics.dog_id IN ANY(dog_ids);
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What I have tried

```
 AND dog_characteristics.dog_id = ANY(dog_ids);
 AND dog_characteristics.dog_id = ANY(dog_ids::int[]);
 AND dog_characteristics.dog_id IN (dog_ids::int[]);
 AND dog_characteristics.dog_id IN (dog_ids);
 AND dog_characteristics.dog_id IN (ARRAY(dog_ids));
 AND dog_characteristics.dog_id IN ARRAY(dog_ids);
 AND dog_characteristics.dog_id IN implode( ',', dog_ids);
```

Most common error

```
  ERROR:  malformed array literal: "672"
  DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
  CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function update_dog_characteristics_guarantor_id() line 5 at SQL statement
```

Comment: `= ANY(dog_ids);` should work

Comment: That gives me the error about the malformed array literal. Is it because it only returns one id?

Comment: I tried <code> = dog_ids </code> and that fails with the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your trigger function.

As `dog_ids` is declared as an array, the result of the first select has to be an array as well. To do that, you need to aggregate all IDs that are returned from the query.

So the first select statement should be

```
 select array_agg(id) --<< aggregate all IDs into an array
   into dog_ids 
 FROM dogs 
 WHERE dogs.family_id = OLD.id;
```

To check if an array has elements, you can't use `select count(*)`, you need to use use `array_length()` or `cardinality()`.

The `&&` is not the "AND" operator in SQL - that's `AND` - so the `if` should be:

```
IF OLD.family_id IS NOT NULL AND cardinality(dog_ids) > 0 THEN
  ... 
END IF;
```

The where condition on the array should be:

```
AND dog_characteristics.dog_id = ANY(dog_ids);
```